# Should I include nuget library path in Additional library directives

Tags: c++, nuget

I have a Visual Studio C++ project which requires zlib library. I am using nuget to manage dependencies.
Should I edit the Additional Library Directive field of Property pages for VS to see the zlib.lib?

Comment: What do you mean to "see the zlib.lib"? If it's on your hard drive, nothing can hide it from you

Comment: "nothing can hide it from you" except for a very very annoying virus

Comment: I mean Visual Studio cannot link to the library. VS just ignores the library.